# Creating every possible combination of multiple columns

Tags: postgresql

I would like to create a query that would output every possibility of multiple columns.  The input would be as follows.

```
Keyword 1|Keyword 2|Keyword 3
---------+---------+----------
shoes    |buy
gloves   |online
shirts   |
```

the second hypothetical input would be the following

```
Keyword 1|Keyword 2|Keyword 3
---------+---------+----------
shoes    |buy      |shop
gloves   |online   
shirts   |
```

the result on the 1rst as follows
    shoes buy,
    gloves buy,
    shirts buy,
    shoes online,
    gloves online,
    shirts online,

the result of the 2nd as follows;
    shoes buy,
    gloves buy,
    shirts buy,
    shoes online,
    gloves online,
    shirts online,
    shoes buy shop,
    gloves buy shop,
    shirts buy shop,
    shoes online shop,
    gloves online shop,
    shirts online shop

Is there a way to write a query that would work in both situations?  The number of columns would potentially change to be up to 5.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do a cartesian join between the same table:

```
select t1.col, t2.col, t3.col
from tab t1, tab t2, tab t3
```

If you want to eliminate duplicates, you can try this trick:

```
select t1.col, t2.col, t3.col
    from tab t1
join tab t2 on t1.col != t2.col
join tab t3 on t2.col != t3.col and t3.col != t1.col
```

You can read about different options here: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-cross-join/

Comment: Thank you for the insight, is it possible to reference columns for this within the same table?

Comment: Yes. As you can see I'm using the same column called `col` from the same table `tab` three times.